# How to use Kinect (Xbox 360) as a Desktop Controller

Tags: 11.10, xbox-360, kinect

I have seen other answers for previous Ubuntu versions that did not solve my problem. For 11.10, what software is available to Install and operate the Kinect controller from the XBox.

Comment: I assumed you meant the Kinect, not the "Kinetic" so edited. Feel free to throw me down a well if that was a bad assumption.

Comment: No biggy ^^ buddy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenKinect is probably your best initial bet. They have a bit in their wiki about [installing for Ubuntu](http://openkinect.org/wiki/Getting_Started#Ubuntu) that I'll summarise below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:floe/libtisch
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libfreenect libfreenect-dev libfreenect-demos
sudo adduser $USER video
```

Then you can run the `freenect-*` demos like `freenect-glview`.

And if that doesn't work (missing package, etc), you can always go back to [the wiki](http://openkinect.org/wiki/Getting_Started#Ubuntu) where they have manual installation instructions.

I should point out that this still doesn't really *do* anything. It's a library for interfacing with the Kinect and a few tech demos. If you want something more specific than what the demos provide, you'll either need to look for different software or you'll need to write something yourself.

Comment: Thanks Oli. I am trying to do a presentation of Ubuntu using the Kinect controller.

Comment: There are multiple sub-projects that do similar stuff to that. Here is one: [Kinect-Mouse](https://github.com/Ooblik/Kinect-Mouse)